# How to Check remaining files of Windows 7 from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

I've just installed Ubuntu (14.04 LTS). Before this, I had dual-boot Windows 7 and Fedora 18, and I tried to uninstall the Fedora, but I did something wrong, so I have to install Ubuntu (because I have its boot CD). I chose to install Ubuntu, and then "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu". Now I cannot open Windows 7 again, as it immediately runs Ubuntu when I turn on the computer.
What I want to do now is to check whether there are some files left from Windows 7. Of course, those files aren't important. I just want to make sure that there aren't. How can I do this?
*Sorry for my English*
Thanks

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks everybody here for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you selected the option `Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu`, the hard drive was formatted as an ext4 partition and hence no Windows related files are on it.

However, data can still be recovered using tools such as `photorec` and hence if you want to completely get rid of your previous data, it is recommended to `zero` the hard drive, ie overwriting with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

> "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu".

This means "remove any and all other operating systems and install Ubuntu".

> Now I cannot open Windows 7 again, as it immediately runs Ubuntu when I turn on the computer.

That is because you removed Windows 7 (and Fedora). When there is just one operating system on a computer it will automatically boot that operating system. When there are 2 or more you get to choose when booting.

> Of course, those files aren't important. I just want to make sure that there aren't. How can I do this?

If you want to check the lay-out of your disk you can install "gParted" and see if there are any partitions labelled as "ntfs". Those are Windows partitions. But I doubt if there will be any.

But in general: foreign partitions will be automatically shown in the launcher after the initial install (the icon is a grey harddisk icon). If those are not there you can also assume there are none on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

If *you've only erased the Fedora partition* and left the Windows partition intact, you might want to press "shift" while booting to show you the boot menu and then choose windows (again: if its partition is intact)

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to "**Erase disk and Install Ubuntu**" during your ubuntu installation there can not possibly be any windows files left .

Because in the "**Erase disk and Install Ubuntu**" step the installer formats your hard drive while converting it from **NTFS**(*default windows file system*) to **ext4**(*ubuntu 14.04's default file system*).

Unless you lost some important data and are looking for ways to recover it.

You really shouldn't be worried!